# Cast volume popup not showing

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm currently integrating the new cast SDK in my music app. I can connect to my cast device (in this case chromecast) and I also can load metadata into it. But when a music is playing and I press any volume keys of my cellphone, the cast volume popup doesn't show up, instead it's showing normal song volume popup.

Am I missing to add any specific code for volume? I saw the CastVideo project on google cast repository but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

[image: Popup]

**EDIT:** When my app is on background and it's casting the cast volume popup appears normally.

Comment: Does it control the cast volume or it changes the local volume? Do you see a drop down when the volume popup appears and if so, when you expand it, do you see any cast volume there?

Comment: It only opens up a popup which controls the local volume (even when it's connected to chromecast). I can only change cast volume when I touch on cast icon and I change on the dialog that shows up. I attached a picture of the popup in my question.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?